# set a function equal to a variable so i can do this($var)

Tags: php

I have  a function `the_search()` that just echoes what people searched for.

I want to put that in to another function, `get_data($var)` to get some data.

How can I set `the_search();` equal to some `$var` so that I can do the following:

```
$thing = get_data('$var');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You could change `the_search` not to `echo` the data, but to `return` it.

b) You could use [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
the_search();
$var = ob_get_clean();
```